# Selecting multiple items or objects in starUML (using ctrl + mouse left click)

Tags: c#, uml, staruml

I am using starUML for class diagram and activity diagram. I am wondering that 'ctrl' (+ mouse left click) doesn't work there. I am not able to select multiple items therefore. so to move or copy multiple objects, you need to put lot of efforts. Though ctrl + A works works, selecting all items is not desired always.

Am i missing something? Is there any other way to select multiple items at a time in starUML? 
Though selecting multiple items using mouse (left click + spanning mouse over multiple items ) is possible, it is not convinient and many times not precise. I am specifically looking for use of 'ctrl' button here.

Thanks in advance,
Ujjwal

Comment: Related to the above, I would like to select multiple items in the tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of control try using the [Shift] button.

From [StarUML User Guide](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/docs/user-guide%28en%29/ch04.html) -

"You may select multiple elements by dragging the mouse over an area. Click the view elements while holding down the [Shift] key to add the elements to the selection."